# ASP.NET MVC - Model Validation regarding its dataType Length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-binding, model

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 1 on a project where I would like to validate my form submission with the ModelBinding helpers, actually I am validating it with ModelState.IsValid but it doesn't seem to consider the dataType length when validating it. For example:

I have a field **nvarchar(70)** called **Name** , but when in my form I submit a name with 200 chars, it pass the validation anyways...anyone knows how to prevent this to happen and make the modelBinding respect the datatype length?

Thanks in advance

---

**Update:** Thanks for the help till now: I'm using just standard Linq associations and modelBinding to validate the models, I hope this can help somehow
Cheers

Comment: What validation framework do you use? Have you set a length validator on you model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [excellent comparison](http://goneale.com/2009/06/25/aspnet-mvc-validation-refresh-best-techniques-frameworks/) from the validation alternatives -so you can select what is better for you ; )

Includes concrete implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to keep your model validation logic out of the binding module. and just feed your ModelState with the validation errors from inside your service layer.

See this [series](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_Validation) from the ASP.Net MVC page for examples : )